# unable to receive full file in tcp client server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, memorystream, ftp-client

**Here is my server code for reading a mp4 file and sending to the client**

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3400);
sock.Bind(ep);
sock.Listen(10);
sock = sock.Accept();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\Entertainment\Songs\Video song\song.mp4",FileMode.Open);      
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
br.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
sock.Send(data);
fs.Close();
sock.Close();
```

**Here is the client code**

```
sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3400);
sock.Connect(ep);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();             
int size = 3190551; // I know the file size is about 30 mb
int rec;
while (size > 0)
{
        byte[] buffer;
        if (size < sock.ReceiveBufferSize)
        {
            buffer = new byte[size];
        }
        else
        {
            buffer = new byte[sock.ReceiveBufferSize];
        }
        rec = sock.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);
        size = size - rec;
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);                
}

byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
FileStream fs = new FileStream("E:/song.mp4",FileMode.Create);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs)
bw.Write(data);
fs.Close();
sock.Close();
```

**At the end i just get the data in between 3 to 4 mb.... im new to socket programming and I don't know where the problem is... whether its sending side or receiving !!!! it looks like I just receive a single chunk of data from the server side **

Comment: int size = 3190551; this is not 30mb! it is around 3mb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
int size = 3190551; // I know the file size is about 30 mb
```

you are reading just **3190551** byte which is **3.04mb** not **30mb**.
try to send length of your file at the beginning of your message so client will know how many bytes it should get from server.

Comment: yeah it was suppose to be **31905511** .... I tried it but now its adding some garbage 4 to 5 mb more than the file size which is croipting corrupting my file... thank u so much for your response

Comment: try to send length of your file at the beginning of your message so client will know how many bytes it should get from server.

Comment: you should not write all of your buffer to memory stream, just number of bytes that are received (rec). correct this line `ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); `